# Discord.py select menu appearing after buttons

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm making a discord.py bot and was testing my **/settings** command. It works fine but there is a problem: the dropdown appears after the buttons but I want it to be above.

Here is my code:

```
class Settings(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.value = None
        self.build_options()

        select = discord.ui.Select(options=self.options)
        select.callback = self.select_option
        self.add_item(select)
        

    def build_options(self):
        if get_name() == "":
            self.options = [
                discord.SelectOption(
                    label=" ",
                    default=True
                )
            ]
        else:
            self.options = [
                discord.SelectOption(
                    label=get_name(),
                    default=True
                )
            ]
    
    async def select_option(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select: discord.ui.Select):
        if select.values[0] == "None":
            await interaction.response.send_message("None", ephemeral=True)
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("None", ephemeral=True)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Add", emoji="<:add:1203694266573127680>", style=discord.ButtonStyle.success)
    async def add_profile(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_modal(New())

    @discord.ui.button(label="Edit", emoji="<:edit:1203694268473151558>", style=discord.ButtonStyle.secondary)
    async def edit_profile(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        ...

    @discord.ui.button(label="Delete", emoji="<:trash:1204886545765503056>", style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger)
    async def delete_profile(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        ...
```

I've tried a lot of ways but none of them worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## For pycord

[Documentation](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/ui_kit.html#discord.ui.Button) says this about buttons:

> row (Optional[int]) – The relative row this button belongs to. A Discord component can only have 5 rows. By default, items are arranged automatically into those 5 rows. If you’d like to control the relative positioning of the row then passing an index is advised. For example, row=1 will show up before row=2. Defaults to None, which is automatic ordering. The row number must be between 0 and 4 (i.e. zero indexed).

[Select](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/ui_kit.html#discord.ui.Select) also has the same parameter.

This means that if you change the `row` parameter, you can set their respective rows.

Your Code:

```py
       select = discord.ui.Select(options=self.options)
```

You could change the above to:

```py
       select = discord.ui.Select(options=self.options, row=0)  # set the row
```

## For discord.py

It should be the same process. See the documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20ui%20select#discord.ui.Select)